# Atom window doesn't show up on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gui, atom

I have a strange problem with my [text editor](https://atom.io/).
 A few days ago I noticed that the editor window doesn't show up, when I started the program.
Then I typed in the cli `atom .` inside a project folder to open it, and it worked.

But recently I've got the same issue, therefore I can't use the editor at all.


I already tried to check with `ps aux|grep atom` and it's shows me Atom is running, but I get no GUI.

After all I tried to kill, and restart it, but nothing changed.

Every answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I just realized what happened with the editor.
I didn't see any GUI when I started the program, but when I moved my mouse in a particular position I saw this.
[image]

And well in the middle of the picture, there is my Atom GUI somehow minimized to 1×5 pixel. After I was able to scale it out, and now works perfectly. Strange, but for now I can use it again.

Comment: happened to me too, except it was at the upper very far left by the ubuntu menu bar.  I think I got there with some weird accidental key combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have the same problem. It simply dissapear.

When I make ALT + TAB not appears Atom in the list of programs but appears another, google-chrome by example. And chosing this Atom retourning to live.

I not understand this stranger, but worked for me.

Bye!

Comment: I tried to switch between the programs with ALT + TAB, but I didn't see any Atom GUI. However your comment helped me to find the solution!

Comment: I am very happy of help you!

Answer (score 0):

I had doubts that the window might be rendered outside the screen coordinates so I used keyboard shortcuts to get Atom window snapped to cursor and move it.

For that I started Atom and pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>. Then the window showed up and I could position it with my mouse.